# Hide button based on hours

Tags: javascript, button, time, hide

On a page, Save button should be visible or hidden based on system time.
I want to hide Save button everyday after 10 AM. 
My broken code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var currentTime = new Date();
 var hours = currentTime.getHours();
 var newButton = document.getElementById("btn1");

if(hours>10) {
 newButton.style.display = "none";
//tried this one too
// document.getElementById('btn1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
else {
 newButton.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

In HTML code I added

```
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit')}" />
```

Any suggestion or help.

Comment: This should work. Is the script tag before or after the element in your HTML?

Comment: Also on a side note: It's pretty easy to circumvent this code, either using dev tools or to adjust my clock settings. You should also implement the same check on your server side code.

Comment: It is at the beginning of page where I put link to css too. So it is before. This is how I put it     <script src="../Style%20Library/name.js"> </script>

Comment: thanks for comment about security, but this is a page to enable or disable users to save their lunch ordering in student restaurant.

Comment: BTW, to stop the button working, use `newButton.disabled = true`. Now it won't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a onload event. Your button isn't on the page yet. An element that isn't rendered yet cannot be addressed.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
     var currentTime = new Date();
     var hours = currentTime.getHours();
     var newButton = document.getElementById("btn1");

    if(hours>10) {
     newButton.style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
     newButton.style.display = "block";
    }
}, false);
```

This way it fires when the page is loaded and the button in question is present.

Or like Deef commented, put the script tag on the bottom of your page.

Comment: @Mouser best practice is to put your scripts at the bottom, this improves performance of initial page load and added bonus is that you don't need to check the load events

Comment: @Deef You are right, however with different types of libraries managing can become a problem. With onload you know that everything is done.

Comment: @Deef Thank you too. Will try this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Your function can be really simple, e.g.:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
  var newButton = document.getElementById("btn1");
  newButton.style.visibility = new Date().getHours() > 10? 'none' : '';
});
```

Note that the default display value for buttons is `inline-block`, but not all browsers will necessarily use that and CSS may be used to set it to some other value. Setting the *display* to "" (empty string) lets it adopt its default or inherited style for the particular browser or style sheet and you don't have to change your code very time the page designer changes her/his mind.

Also, to really disable the button, you should set it's *disabled* property to true.